# Останавливается цикл при записи в базу данных

Tags: python, циклы, sqlite3

Я пишу программу на питоне что-то в духе "калькулятора" для игры (EVE Online). Задача самой программы заключается в том что-бы рассчитать выгодную руду для каждого минерала. Суть проблемы такова что когда код входит в первый цикл `for` он затягивает с БД таблицы Required значения и записывает в переменные а потом заходит во второй цикл `for`, и там он сравнивает значения для расчета и записи в другую БД таблици Calculated но цикл выполняет 1 итерацию и прекращает что либо делать дальше. Сама программа не зависает можно еще раз что-то "рассчитать". Прошу помощи в решении данной проблемы или примеры других вариантов.

```py
class Foo:
    def f():
        required = {}
        index = []
        for i in sql.execute("SELECT * FROM Required"):
            required[i[0]] = i[1]
            index.append(i[0])
        for i in sql.execute("SELECT * FROM minerals_in_ore"):
            for key in required:
                if key == i[1]:
                    result = (required[key] * 100) / (i[2] * (efficiency / 100))
                    print(i[0], i[1], math.ceil(result))
                    sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO Calculated (Ore, Minerals, Count) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (i[0], i[1], math.ceil(result))) # обрывается цикл
                    db.commit()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = eve_calore()
application.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

P.S. я не много имею опыта в питоне и базе данных. И я прекрастно понимаю что моя "проблемма" может быть очевидной и по-этому попрошу не судить строго.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная `sql` это курсор, отдав новую команду в `sql.execute(f"INSERT`  Вы обрываете курсор `sql.execute("SELECT`

Или соханите все данные из SELECT во временный массив или создайте новый курсор для INSERT.

Comment: Большое тебе спасибо, сработало. я просто создал еще `sql2 = db.cursor()`. Я чуть не завизжал от счастья))

Comment: Если все хорошо, ставьте галочку ;)